# Accessing objects in resource (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have the following code and what I want is be able to access (get reference to) the MenuItem objects in my ListBox resource but I have no idea how.

```
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MouseDoubleClick="MainListBox_MouseDoubleClick" Name="mainListBox" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Click="OpenMenuItem_Click" Header="Open" Name="openMenuItem"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Click="CutMenuItem_Click" Header="Cut" Name="cutMenuItem"/>
                <MenuItem Click="CopyMenuItem_Click" Header="Copy" Name="copyMenuItem"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Click="DeleteMenuItem_Click" Header="Delete" Name="deleteMenuItem"/>
                <MenuItem Click="RenameMenuItem_Click" Header="Rename" Name="renameMenuItem"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
renameMenuItem.IsEnabled = false;
```

But first I need to get reference to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var ctx = (ContextMenu)mainListBox.FindResource("ContextMenu");
var renameMenuItem = (MenuItem)ctx.Items[6];
renameMenuItem.IsEnabled = false;
```

You can find any MenuItems and Separators in `ctx.Items`

**UPDATE :**

This is an alternative to find MenuItem by name as you asked in comment:

```
foreach (var item in ctx.Items)
{
    if (item is MenuItem && ((MenuItem)item).Name == "renameMenuItem")
    {
        var renameMenuItem = (MenuItem) item;
        renameMenuItem.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But is there a way to do the same by using the name defined? If I rearrange my MenuItem objects I don't want to have to change my C#.